# How can I get Excel to display a long number in full?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have already went through all previous questions but didn't find an answer to my question.
I need to display this number `4935320154684405` but there's no way Excel let me do it. It displays `4,93532E+15` or `4935320154684400` but never the correct one.

How can I get Excel to display the number in full?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Have you tried to change the cell format to text so it will allow the entire number to be displayed?

Comment: Thank you CharlieRB, changing cell format to text let it display the number as I want but is useless if i need to use it for calculation

Comment: Sorry. You asked how to display it, but said nothing about using it in a calculation. That is an important detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a custom cell format.
Select the cell format dropdown and change it to select the number of digits required.

You can remove the comma separators as you wish

[image: Screengrab of format dialogue]

Comment: Thanks Chemunka, I already tried with custom in cell format but it doesn't work